# while passing parameter in stored procedure getting error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
alter procedure [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReport]
as
begin
   DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
           @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
           @locid INTEGER

   select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(Vtype) 
                         from VType_tbl
                        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

   set @query = 'SELECT Date, ' + @cols + ' 
                from 
                (
                   select v.Vtype, convert(date, dtime) as Date 
                   from Transaction_tbl t
                   inner join VType_tbl v on t.vtid = v.vtid
                   where locid =  ' + CAST(@locid as varchar(max)) + ') d
                pivot 
                (
                   count(Vtype)
                   for Vtype in (' + @cols + ')
                ) p '

   execute(@query)
end
```

Comment: i edited stored procedure what ever you said,while executing  still am getting error like this:Procedure ParkingDeatailsReport has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error message you're getting, along with what you tried.

Answer (score 4):

Notice the difference between @cols and @locid in dynamic SQL.

**Replace**

```
where locid = @locid
```

**With**

```
where locid = ' + CAST(@locid as varchar(max)) + '
```

Note: while this is a quick fix please see answer from RBarryYoung for best practice with dynamic SQL.

Comment: i didnt get u,,,,i re write my code what ever you said,,,still am getting error while executing

Comment: that was not smart to change your original code with my answer and then tell me you get some other errors, hence the downvote ;)

Comment: this error is getting:Procedure ParkingDeatailsReport has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

Comment: @user2432269 Because you moved the declaration of @locid. It should be right before `as begin..`

Comment: i can give two declaration in one procdeure

Comment: @user2432269 move the declaration of `@locid` where it originally was. Between `alter procedure [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReport]` and `as begin`.

Comment: sir,,,i got,,,i did what ever you said,,,,,thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

the error clearly say, your current SP code not accepting any parameters and you trying to pas parameters to SP. if you want to accept parameters in SP, syntax is:

```
Create Procedure Procedure-name 
(
Input parameters ,
Output Parameters (If required)
)
As
Begin
     Sql statement used in the stored procedure
End
```

So in your case SP can be change to :

```
alter procedure [dbo].[ParkingDeatailsReport]
 (
      @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @locid INTEGER
 )
as
begin
   ..... you code go hear 
END
```